# Check if string is neither empty nor space in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd

I am trying to run the following shell script which is supposed to check if a string is neither space nor empty. However, I am getting the same output for all the 3 mentioned strings. I have tried using the "[[" syntax as well but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
str="Hello World"
str2=" "
str3=""

if [ ! -z "$str" -a "$str"!=" " ]; then
        echo "Str is not null or space"
fi

if [ ! -z "$str2" -a "$str2"!=" " ]; then
        echo "Str2 is not null or space"
fi

if [ ! -z "$str3" -a "$str3"!=" " ]; then
        echo "Str3 is not null or space"
fi
```

I am getting the following output:

```
# ./checkCond.sh 
Str is not null or space
Str2 is not null or space
```

Comment: Are empty strings known as null strings in shell scripting?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You need a space on either side of the `!=`. Change your code to:

```
str="Hello World"
str2=" "
str3=""

if [ ! -z "$str" -a "$str" != " " ]; then
        echo "Str is not null or space"
fi

if [ ! -z "$str2" -a "$str2" != " " ]; then
        echo "Str2 is not null or space"
fi

if [ ! -z "$str3" -a "$str3" != " " ]; then
        echo "Str3 is not null or space"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But I wonder why the assignment doesn't use a space whereas a comparison does.

Comment: ^^It's syntax. The first word on the command line is the command & subsequent ones are arguments. `var=value [command [args]]` is the syntax, in which a variable is assigned value. for comparison, `[` (`/usr/bin/[`) is the command & it requires var1, != & var2 to be 3 separate arguments. var1!=var2 is a single argument.

Answer (score 94):

For checking the empty string in shell

```
if [ "$str" == "" ];then
   echo NULL
fi
```

OR

```
if [ ! "$str" ];then
   echo NULL
fi
```

Comment: The shell's string equality operator is `=`. The `==` is a non-portable hack invented by shell authors to mess up the minds of young programmers.

Answer (score 43):

Another quick test for a string to have something in it but space.

```
if [[ -n "${str// /}" ]]; then
    echo "It is not empty!"
fi
```

"-n" means non-zero length string.

Then the first two slashes mean match *all* of the following, in our case space(s). Then the third slash is followed with the replacement (empty) string and closed with "}". Note the difference from the usual regular expression syntax.

You can read more about [string manipulation in bash shell scripting here](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: isn't `[[ -n "$1" ]]` the same as `[[ ! -z "$1" "]]`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills you are right, using -n would make it a bit shorter. I just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The quickest solution here, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

In case you need to check against any amount of whitespace, not just single space, you can do this:

To strip string of extra white space (also condences whitespace in the middle to one space):

```
trimmed=`echo -- $original`
```

The `--` ensures that if `$original` contains switches understood by echo, they'll still be considered as normal arguments to be echoed. Also it's important to not put `""` around `$original`, or the spaces will not get removed.

After that you can just check if `$trimmed` is empty.

```
[ -z "$trimmed" ] && echo "empty!"
```

Comment: In bourne shell I end up with "--" as the value of trimmed.

Comment: According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean), echo does not interpret -- to mean the end of options. In my Bash shell, I get the same result as Sridhar Sarnobat

Answer (score 10):

To check if a string is empty or contains only whitespace you could use:

```
shopt -s extglob  # more powerful pattern matching

if [ -n "${str##+([[:space:]])}" ]; then
    echo '$str is not null or space'
fi
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the Bash Manual.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ $(echo $variable_to_test | sed s/\n// | sed s/\ //) == "" ] && echo "String is empty"
```

Stripping all newlines and spaces from the string will cause a blank one to be reduced to nothing which can be tested and acted upon

Comment: I think the `g` flag is missing in sed commands, to change *all* occurences:
`[ $(echo $variable_to_test | sed s/\n//g | sed s/\ //g) == "" ] && echo "String is empty"`