# Use a select menu to navigate directories

Tags: bash

I am using `Ubuntu server` and I want to create `BASH` script that would help me to navigate through directories at ease.

I found this piece of code and I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/ftp/server/googledrive

prompt="Please select a file:"
options=( $(ls -1) )

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        echo  "You picked $opt which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done
```

However it only lists the directories, each of them having a corresponding number. Is it possible to make it in such a way that I can actually navigate through my directories?

**EDIT:** Thank you the comments. I should have done this when I created the post.

By "actual navigation" I mean this: the main goal was being able to select a .zip archive and unzip it in a specific folder, thus the navigation part. So you would have to navigate from Directory A to B and then to C. Starting from the first directory you would have all the directories listed and each of them having an unique number, by selecting a number you would then navigate to that specific directory. This would repeat until you would find the directory you need and then select an option like "Unzip here".

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Much safer to have `options=( * )`

Comment: ...speaking to the question, though: What do you mean by "actually navigate"? Do you mean you want a curses-style interface? Then you should use something like `dialog`. Do you just mean you want your code to `cd` into the directory you select, *and leave your shell in that new directory when it exits*? Then you'll want to see [Why doesn't `cd` work in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script).

Comment: ...and if you *do* want a curses-style tool to navigate a directory tree, is there a reason you're writing your own rather than using something that already exists? I know of at least three. (All of them either work by creating a new and different shell instance in the target directory, or being wrapped in / implemented as a shell function, as a program can't change the working directory of the separate process that started it without that process's participation).

Comment: Have a look [there: How do I prompt...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script/27875395#27875395)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am a newbie bash programmer and I truly appreciate your help. I edited my post so you know exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Do something like `while :; do options=( * ); select ...` for your outer loop. Then put in a `if [[ -d "$REPLY" ]]; then cd "$REPLY" || echo "Unable to access directory $REPLY" >&2; elif [[ -f "$REPLY" ]]; then unzip "$REPLY"; break; fi`, or whatever, inside your relevant `if` branch. Point being every time through the loop, you're potentially in a different directory per the instructions you got from the user, so your glob expands to a different list.

Comment: BTW, code formatting is only for *code* -- "Ubuntu server" is English text, not code; no need to put it in backticks. See discussion on Meta at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try everything you wrote and I am sorry for not following the guidelines regarding text formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for a similar requirement described in the post.

In my case, I have a set of preferred directories that I navigate to regularly.  I keep this list of directories in a file called `~/dirs.txt`

In `~/.bashrc` I have set up 2 aliases to support accessing the directory list:

1. *add parent directory*: `apd`

> Add the current path I'm at,  into the `~/dirs.txt` file

2. *change current directory*: `ccd`

> Lists each line as a menu option, and from the choice selected - then navigate to the directory for that menu item

```
alias apdnwln="echo '  '  >> ~/dirs.txt"
alias apd=" pwd >> ~/dirs.txt; apdnwln"
alias ccd="showCcdMenu"

showCcdMenu(){

  echo "----------------"
  echo "    Go To path: "
  echo "----------------"
  echo ""

  dirsFile='/Users/someusername/dirs.txt'
  IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
  set -f          # disable globbing

  count=0
  for i in $(cat < "$dirsFile"); do
    #Trimming white space
    value=${i// }
    if [ "$value" == "" ];then
      printf "\n"
      continue
    fi

    count=$((count+1))
    if [[ ( "$count"  -lt "10" ) ]] ; then
       printf " "
    fi
    echo " $count : $value"
  done

  printf "\n"
  echo "Enter your choice"
  read itemChoice
  echo "your choice: $itemChoice"

  count=0
  for i in $(cat < "$dirsFile"); do
    #Trimming white space
    value=${i// }
    if [ "$value" == "" ];then
      printf "\n"
      continue
    fi

    count=$((count+1))

    if [[ ( "$count"  -eq "$itemChoice" ) ]] ; then

      echo " going to dir: $i"
      cd $i
      break
    fi
  done
}
```

The following SO (& Co.) posts made this solt. possible .. thanks SO!

- [Why can't I change directories using "cd" in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file
- [How can I compare numbers in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807585
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509643
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807585
- https://askubuntu.com/a/385531

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple example to give you some ideas. Entering the number of a directory enters it. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> pops back up a level.

```
#!/bin/sh

function selector {
    select name in *; do
        if [ -d "$name" ]; then
            cd "$name"
            selector
            cd ..
        fi
    done
}

selector
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I followed your solution and also the comments and I finally made the script work how I wanted it to work. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

this project creates a excellent menu for cd history.

https://github.com/xhawk18/fast_cd_menu

To install it, try ---

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xhawk18/fast_cd_menu/master/install.sh | bash
```