# Bash check if command returns output, and print it

Tags: bash

```
if ! output=$(some_command);
then
    printf "Error occurred, error output is =\n%s", "$output"
```

Could you please suggest if this is a good way to do it?
I am testing -
If the exit status of the command is 1, then only I want to print the contents of the output.
If the exit status of the command is 0, then do nothing. Don't print output.

Comment: Try `output="$(some_command)"; if [[ -n $output ]]; then printf "output is =\n%s" "$output"; fi`

Comment: The construct in your condition (with `!`) is testing the _exit status_ of the command, not the contents of the variable. It is very useful in that aspect, just not as the text of your question describes.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I have updated as per your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't allow you to print data before the output of the command, but after:

```
if some_command | grep .; then
    echo "the output was as above"
fi
```

If you really want to print text before, you can store it and do:

```
if output=$(some_command | grep .); then
    printf "the output is:%s\n" "$output"
fi
```

Or you can be more explicit and do:

```
output=$(some_command)
if test -n "$output"; then
    printf "the output is:%s\n" "$output"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You're testing whether the command was successful, not whether it returned output.

Assign the variable separately from the `if` statement.

```
output=$(some_command)
if [ -n "$output" ]
then
    printf "output is =\n%s", "$output"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print when there is no output? I read this as `if not output print the following`

If you want to print when it output is not null the following should work...

More info here:
[Check if string is neither empty nor space in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509508/check-if-string-is-neither-empty-nor-space-in-shell-script)

```
temp=$(command)
if [[ -n "${temp// /}" ]];; then
        echo "output is $temp"
fi
```